# How to use LOOKUP from bottom to top when the data compared is a text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've looked up how to search for the last time an entry appears in a column and came across this solution:

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/730228-vlookup-from-bottom-to-top.html

which seems to work fine when the data is a number. However, I'm searching for the last time a name appears in my table and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to adapt this solution.

Is there any other method I could use?

Edit: the solution above does work! I must have been doing something wrong. As per comments, it worked for me.

Comment: That formula works with text, what is the actual formula you tried?

Comment: This will work with text - see [explanation1](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/717811-variable-cell-reference-based-on-minimum-difference.html#post2252293) or [explanations2](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/lookup-for-a-value-in-unsorted-data.99621/#post-492425).

Comment: What you are trying can be achieved for Text as well as Number also, please [Edit] your post & share some sample data with us !

Comment: Well, I'm unsure what I was doing wrong, but I just tried it again and it did work. The first time I read explanation1 @harrymc, it wasn't clear to me, but now I understand why it works. Anyways, sorry for the hassle and thank you!